# setTimeout runs its callback codes much slower than without it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, settimeout

We are struggling with a strange issue in using `setTimeout` function in Javascript at the React.
As using codes inside the `setTimeout`, it runs much slower than running the codes without the `setTimeout`!

As a comparison, the performance is resulted in:

> Using `setTimeout`: **1391 ms**
>   without using `setTimeout`: **15 ms**

**In API callback (eg. `axios`), the setTimeout version happens as well!**

A simple sample code is shown in the following:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-kowalevski-2clr0)

Can anyone explain what is happening?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [time, setTime] = useState("");

  const startSample = () => {
    const startTimeStamp = new Date().valueOf();
    for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      setValue(`test-${i}`);
      // console.log(`test-${i}`);
    }
    const endTimeStamp = new Date().valueOf();
    setTime(`${endTimeStamp - startTimeStamp}ms`);
  };

  const handleClick1 = () => {
    startSample();
  };

  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      startSample();
    });
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
      <p>{value || "Please push that button!"}</p>
      <div>
        <button id="startBtn" onClick={handleClick1}>
          Start Normal
        </button>
        <button id="startBtn1" onClick={handleClick2}>
          Start With setTimeout
        </button>
      </div>
      <p>Result: {time}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This is an old issue. When wrapped with `setTimeout` you're actually generating 5 thousand renders instead of just one

Comment: Both are executed in the same way, the difference is that react won't batch updates that aren't triggered inside a React event handle. See the quote from M Erikson in my answer

Comment: What's the solution for the callbacks like axios which acts like the `setTimeout` version

Comment: Also in my answer. Use an accumulator and call set state just once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React batches renders that are queued up within an event callback, so all of your calls to `setValue` in the click handler result in a single render once your handler finishes.

However, I do not believe React batches renders from within a setTimeout call.  So it is rendering after each call to `setValue` in your setTimeout handler.

See this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259

You should be able to make the setTimeout version faster by writing it like so:

```
const handleClick2 = () => {
  setTimeout(() => ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => startSample()));
}
```

If you have a bunch of async ajax responses coming back and want to apply them after they all arrive, then you might have code like this:

```
const [a, setA] = useState();
const [b, setB] = useState();
const [c, setC] = useState();
const [d, setD] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const a = await fetchA();
    const b = await fetchB();
    const c = await fetchC();
    const d = await fetchD();

    // wrap all of the state updates in batchUpdates
    // so that we only get one render instead of 4
    ReactDOM.unstable_batchUpdates(() => {
      setA(a);
      setB(b);
      setC(c);
      setD(d);
    });
  })()
}), []);
```

Comment: both codes are executed in the same situation. The only difference is using or not-using the `setTimeout`

Comment: yes the `setTimeout` call is causing your updates to run _outside_ the event handler so React does not batch the renders. The `unstable_batchUpdates` is how you get your code "back inside" a React batch rendering context.

Comment: Brandon, what's the solution for the callbacks like axios which acts like the `setTimeout` version!?

Comment: run your batch of state updates inside a call to `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates`.  I'll post a short example, but without seeing your code I don't know how well it fits.

Answer (score 4):

> React currently will batch state updates if they're triggered from
>   within a React-based event, like a button click or input change. It
>   will not batch updates if they're triggered outside of a React event
>   handler, like a setTimeout().

Consider the following

```
  const startSample = () => {
    const startTimeStamp = new Date().valueOf();
    const arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      arr.push(i)
      // console.log(`test-${i}`);
    }
    setValue(arr)
    const endTimeStamp = new Date().valueOf();
    setTime(`${endTimeStamp - startTimeStamp}ms`);
  };
```

Now both times are about the same right? As pointed out by Brandon React doesn't seem to wait all udpates finishes before triggering a new render, resulting in five thousand renders instead of just one. So use an accumulator to perform the iterations and set the state just once